# Javascript rsa 2048 bit clientside encryption

Tags: javascript, html, encryption, cryptography, rsa

I'm trying to perform client side javascript rsa 2048 encryption on long texts > 1000 characters  along with asynchronous 2048 bit key generation which is the best library for doing this ?

Comment: Please see this article: http://www.matasano.com/articles/javascript-cryptography/

Answer (score 0):

Try [asmcrypto.js](https://github.com/vibornoff/asmcrypto.js), I've recently added RSA support. Also AES to «encrypto long texts > 1000 characters» is already under the hood.

I'm an author of the library and answer any questions related to asmcrypto.js if any.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you're trying to achieve, you may be able to accomplish it with Subtle.Crypto.

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/SubtleCrypto